# image into base64 string as an input to call a web service

Tags: php, image

i have converted an image to and froth base64 string,but now i would like to upload an image and then convert it into a base64string,and i would like to send this string as an input to call the web service.
the code i am using is

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
 }
}
 else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: And I don't see any `base64` here. What did you try?

Comment: this is the ready made code from w3 schools tutorials ,i wanted to store the image into a place as i am complete newbie to php tutorial i am stuck here

Comment: ⇧ calling for help like that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$image= file_get_contents("/path/to/image.jpg");
$convertedData= base64_encode($imagedata);
```

**edit**
It seems you do not know basic php. should i help you?

**I am echoing base64 formated code**

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
{
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"].'<br />';

  /* Notice here */
  $image = file_get_contents("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  $convertedData = base64_encode($imagedata);
  echo 'Base64 Inmage code :'.$convertedData;
  /* My edits end here */


  }
 }
}
 else
{
echo "Invalid file";
}
?>
```

Comment: i have created a html page <form action="file.php" method="post"/>
Image
<input type="file" name="image">
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

Comment: then i have added this to file.php but no luck i get nothing ,were am i going wrong , $image= file_get_contents("/path/to/image.jpg");
$convertedData= base64_encode($imagedata);

Comment: You also have to change the name to file.  I mean `<input type="file" name="file" />`

Comment: thank you i will try this ,yes i am trying to study php,only have a 2 weeks experience in php